# mocking data for Robotium Test cases

Tags: android, mocking, robotium

I have gone through basic robotium tutorials. I need more knowledge regarding mocking the data for robotium test cases. which website/link or book should i follow ?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small introduction [here](http://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2012/10/18/runtime-replace-implementations-with-roboguice-in-functional-tests/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Please, include at least short description in your answer as websites are going away eventually and the information is lost.